# Browser font has changed

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts

Recently, the font in my browser has changed when I google something. This is not related to Google Chrome as I noticed, because when I google something in Microsoft Edge or other browsers, it looks the same in all of them. Does anyone know what I can do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOp0o.png)

As you can see the text is very long and looks ugly.

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong in your screenshot, have you attached the right screenshot?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQib6.png
Look this, then you see the differences

Comment: I am pretty sure that's related to Google - they just decided to use another font to display their results !

Answer (score -1):

the font definitely changed. And I don't like it.
If you take a closer look, the capital letter G is now the same as it is in their logo.
So far it showed up only in Firefox. When I tried it on MS Edge and Chrome, it showed the old font.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQib6.png)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Do you know what I can do about it? This font annoys me very much

Comment: Does not answer the question